# python - how to assign a special index to the data frame?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the follwoing dataframe:

```
Col1    Col2      Col3   
X       Apple      A 
Y       Orange     B
Y       Apple      B
X       Apple      B
X       Orange     B
```

I want to create a 4 digit number for creating a Index
The logic is that when Col1 and Col2 is matched, the 4 digit number will be same as previous.
The Index is created by combining Number and Col3

```
Expected output
Number  Col1    Col2      Col3   Index
0001    X       Apple      A     0001-A
0002    Y       Orange     B     0002-B 
0003    Y       Apple      B     0003-B
0001    X       Apple      B     0001-B
0004    X       Orange     B     0004-B
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you add your own attempt to code? so that it'd be easier to know what datatypes you are using and which modules.

Answer (score 0):

first make a dictionary for the number part of index, using the concatenation of column 1 and 2, then you have the number part of index of all the rows, so simply concatenate the index with column 3.

Function to get the index number:

```py
def get_index_number(row,index_dict):
   unique_name=row['col1']+"-"+row['col2']
   if unique_name not in index_dict:
      index_dict[unique_name]=row['number']
   return index_dict[unique_name]
```

Usage:
assuming you already have column 'index' in dataframe (if not add it)

```py
index_dict={}
for row in dataframe.iterrows():
   row['index']=get_index_number(row,index_dict)
```